# A tag jungle: formatting, typography, typesetting?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have noticed that we have got three tags with very similar topics:

- [formatting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) (61×)
- [typesetting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) (17×)
- [typography](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) (18×)

(Only very few questions are tagged by more of them.)

I see a large overlap, surely between typesetting and typography. To me, it seems that these two topics are identical, and refer to the same thing: How to change the "raw text" into "typeset text", and I suggest these two to be synonymised.

I'm not sure though about formatting, I can see some differences between formatting and the other two tags; formatting is more general and can refer to more than just "putting text on paper". However: (1) the difference is small and probably quite subjective; (2) people do not distinguish the tags, it more seems that they simply choose one of the three tags for their question, quite arbitrarily. But as I say, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest to synonymise all of them with the master being [formatting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting).

On Stack Exchange, tags have mainly two purposes:

- To help users who search a solution to some problem they have (so they do not ask a duplicate question).
- To help users who want to answer question about a certain topic, in particular by enabling them to favourite or subscribe to certain tags.

Most users from the first group will not be aware of the nuances between formatting, typesetting and typography and thus synomysing will help them. While in theory there could be users in the second group that care only about one of the topics and for example would subscribe to [formatting](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) but not to [typography](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography), I would be surprised if one actually exists – who is interested in one of these topics in an academia context is also sufficiently interested in the other ones to at least want to read the title of the corresponding questions.

Comment: Note that there is altogether only 2 followers on the three tags, both on [tag:formatting].

Comment: Since you had previously suggested a synonym pair with [tag:typography] and [tag:typesetting], it wasn't possible to suggest either of those as a synonym for [tag:formatting]. I went ahead and deleted your typography-typesetting pair and set them up as formatting synonyms.

Comment: @ff524: I would have suggested a synonym with master *formatting* myself, but I did not have the required score in that tag … You may also want to tag the question *status-completed.*